# validation form using php code

Tags: php, forms

Hi i am trying to build a form and insert the data to my db it's working perfect now i want to make it validation using php to prevent span inputs i am beginner at php so p;ease i need help with this

and the php code

```
      <?php
     $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

        if(!$con)
         {echo'not connect';}

       if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'form'))
        {echo'not selected';}
         $name=$_POST['name'];
         $phone=$_POST['phone'];
         $nationality=$_POST['nationality'];
         $country=$_POST['country'];
         $sql = "INSERT INTO newform(Name,Number,Nationality,Country)                   VALUES('$name','$phone','$nationality','$country')";
          if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
         {echo'not insert';}
        else
        {
            echo'insertes';
         }
        header("refresh:2;url=form.php");
          ?>
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
<?php
$error = false;
$nameErr = $phoneErr = $nationalErr = $countErr = "";
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$con)
{
    echo 'not connect';
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'form'))
{
    echo' DB not selected';
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $nationality=$_POST['nationality'];
    $country=$_POST['country'];
    if($name ==""){
        $error = true;
        $nameErr = "Name field is empty";
    }
    if($phone ==""){
        $error = true;
        $phoneErr = "phone field is empty";
    }
    if($nationality ==""){
        $error = true;
        $nationalErr = "nationality field is empty";
    }
    if($country ==""){
        $error = true;
        $countErr = "country field is empty";
    }
    if($error == false){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO newform(Name,Number,Nationality,Country) VALUES($name,$phone,$nationality,$country')";
        if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            echo 'Values not insert';
        }else
        {
            header("refresh:2;url=form.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<p  style="color:red"><?php echo $nameErr ?></p>
<br>
phone:<br>
<input type="text" name="phone">
<p  style="color:red"><?php echo $phoneErr ?></p>
<br><br>
Nationality:<br>
<input type="text" name="nationality">
<p  style="color:red"><?php echo $nationalErr ?></p>
<br><br>
Country:<br>
<input type="text" name="country">
<p style="color:red"><?php echo $countErr ?></p>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Reference Link:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_required